# How to handle Transaction Rollback for multiple database calls (Calling firebase and mongoDB Atlas)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase

So here is my scenario:

1. I have a Firebase database
2. I also have a MongoDB Atlas database
3. There is a scenario where I have to write to a collection in a MongoDB Atlas database, then another write to a collection in a Firebase database and finally a completion write back to the MongoDB Atlas database.

This is how I handle this:

1. I start a MongoDB transaction
2. I perform a write to MongoDB (in case this fails, I can just rollback no issues)
3. I perform a write to Firebase (in case this fails, I can still cancel MongoDB commit and rollback)
4. I perform another final write to MongoDB (ISSUE HERE)
5. I then commit the MongoDB transaction (ISSUE HERE)

As you can see that in points 4 and 5, if the operation fails, the writes to MongoDB can be rolled back but not the writes to Firebase. Obviously because both these databases are not linked and are not under the same systems. How does one approach this? I'm sure there are lots of systems out there with multiple databases.

I am using NodeJS and Express to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many strategies:

1. Accept the changes in the non-transactional database even if the transaction fails.  Accept that the non-transactional database may have incorrect data. For example, depending on how you view notifications here on SO the number of notifications in the top nav bar can be wrong.
2. Have a janitor process that periodically goes through the transactional database and updates the non-transactional database to match.
3. Same as 2 but trigger the janitor when a transaction is aborted, when you know some changes would need to be made on the non-transactional database.
4. Perform another write to non-transactional database after the transaction completes. This way you'll miss data from some completed transactions in the non-transactional database but you won't have data from aborted transactions there.
5. When reading, read from transactional database first before reading from non-transactional database. If the data isn't present in transactional database, skip non-transactional read.
6. Expire data from non-transactional database to reduce the time when the data there is incorrect.

Comment: Very insightful. I never thought about a periodic janitor approach. Right now I do have a fall back delete to the firebase data incase the mongo db commit fails but this was me being paranoid for the scenario where "what if that firebase delete fails as well". Thanks foe the answer

Comment: Just to add another insight because points 4 & 5 are a bit confusing, my requirement is to just do a batch write but the problem is that its a batch write to firebase and mongoDB as well so if one write fails, all writes must fail. With regards to that, I don't seem to understand points 4 & 5, care to summarise that?

Comment: Firebase transactions work by reading data then checking the read data before the commit. Mongo transactions work by document lock. So reading is not my issue here. Writing to multiple databases as a batch write success or batch write fail is

Comment: I am not talking about reads during writes. At some point you read the data you wrote into both databases, *then* read from transactional one to verify transaction was committed prior to reading from non-transactional one.